# Transaction reverted by EVM

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

I am getting this error

```
Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0x9d45a5c17592d8b93b64114971979526d0a0423f444b04c200e84926492db638",
  "blockNumber": 10351615,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 938316,
  "effectiveGasPrice": 2500000029,
  "from": "0xfc2df69df76fe18866bfc5396f35255e7efa274a",
  "gasUsed": 168954,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x662996eefff173898d6ea30455d9332d5dc7e8a9",
  "transactionHash": "0x08674e3a0ef069075a3fe21dce389560b7ebaf01918bf89417ebb4268e9b505c",
  "transactionIndex": 5,
  "type": "0x2",
  "events": {}
}
```

**Smart contract**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract marketPlaceBoilerPlate is ReentrancyGuard {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _itemIds;
    Counters.Counter private _itemsSold;
    
     address public owner;
     
     constructor() {
         owner = msg.sender;
     }
     
     struct MarketItem {
         uint itemId;
         address nftContract;
         uint256 tokenId;
         address payable seller;
         address payable owner;
         uint256 price;
         bool sold;
     }
     
     mapping(uint256 => MarketItem) private idToMarketItem;
     
     event MarketItemCreated (
        uint indexed itemId,
        address indexed nftContract,
        uint256 indexed tokenId,
        address seller,
        address owner,
        uint256 price,
        bool sold
     );
     
     event MarketItemSold (
         uint indexed itemId,
         address owner
         );
     
    
    
    function createMarketItem(
        address nftContract,
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint256 price
        ) public payable nonReentrant {
            require(price > 0, "Price must be greater than 0");
            
            _itemIds.increment();
            uint256 itemId = _itemIds.current();
  
            idToMarketItem[itemId] =  MarketItem(
                itemId,
                nftContract,
                tokenId,
                payable(msg.sender),
                payable(address(0)),
                price,
                false
            );
            
            IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
                
            emit MarketItemCreated(
                itemId,
                nftContract,
                tokenId,
                msg.sender,
                address(0),
                price,
                false
            );
        }
        
    function createMarketSale(
        address nftContract,
        uint256 itemId
        ) public payable nonReentrant {
            uint price = idToMarketItem[itemId].price;
            uint tokenId = idToMarketItem[itemId].tokenId;
            bool sold = idToMarketItem[itemId].sold;
            require(msg.value == price, "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase");
            require(sold != true, "This Sale has alredy finnished");
            emit MarketItemSold(
                itemId,
                msg.sender
                );

            idToMarketItem[itemId].seller.transfer(msg.value);
            IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
            idToMarketItem[itemId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
            _itemsSold.increment();
            idToMarketItem[itemId].sold = true;
        }
        
    function fetchMarketItems() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
        uint itemCount = _itemIds.current();
        uint unsoldItemCount = _itemIds.current() - _itemsSold.current();
        uint currentIndex = 0;

        MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](unsoldItemCount);
        for (uint i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
            if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == address(0)) {
                uint currentId = i + 1;
                MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
                items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
                currentIndex += 1;
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
      
}
```

**Address**:0x662996eeffF173898D6Ea30455d9332d5DC7E8A9

I am calling the `list` function in my react frontend

```
async function list(nft, listPrice) {
    setLoading(true);
    console.log('nft data inside list:',nft)
    console.log('marketAddress: ',marketAddress);
    const p = listPrice * ("1e" + 18);
    const ops = {
      contractAddress: marketAddress,
      functionName: listItemFunction,
      abi: contractABIJson,
      params: {
        nftContract: nft.token_address,
        tokenId: nft.token_id,
        price: String(p),
      },
    };

    await contractProcessor.fetch({
      params: ops,
      onSuccess: () => {
        console.log("success");
        setLoading(false);
        setVisibility(false);
        addItemImage();
        succList();
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        console.log(error)
        setLoading(false);
        failList();
      },
    });
  }
```

I looked at the similar questions posted here but nothing solves the issue

Comment: Which network are you using? What function are you calling? What parameters are you using?

Comment: I have deployed this on contract on Rinkeby test net and also updated the code above

Comment: I tried debugging it in remix but I am a beginner so I had no clue what I was doing

Comment: Sorry, but it is not obvious what function are you calling, the front-end code doesn't have an explicit interaction with a contract. I'd guess that list might call `fetchMarketItems` but it is a view function so it shouldn't generate a transaction. It might be that you are beginner but that contract wasn't written by one, I'd suggest contacting the creator first.